# Different SSH keys for different paths

Tags: mercurial, ssh, key, host, ssh-keys

I am trying to find a way to use different ssh keys to clone different projects from bitbucket. I tried using ssh_config but I managed to define a different ssh key **only** for connections for a **single particular host**.

What I 'd like to achieve is having

**Key A** for bitbucket.org/myteam1/myproject

and

**Key B** for bitbucket.org/myteam2/myotherproject

Could help me out with this?

Comment: You will have to select an ssh key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found out that the best solution for me is using the `-e sshcommand` option and inside it the `-i key` option to specify the private key that I want.

Answer (score 1):

Far and away the easiest way to to just use ssh-agent.  When you're running ssh-agent you add all you keys and it tries each of them until one works.  Your OS is very possibly already running ssh-agent, so try

```
ssh-add /path/to/key1
ssh-add /path/to/key2
```

then when you try to connect if either key works you're in.  If you're not running ssh-agent you can start it with (on unix/OS X):

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

and then add the two key files.

If for some reason you just can't bear to use ssh-agent, then I've found a workaround using a slightly tricky `.ssh/config` file.  Something like this:

```
Host myteam1.bitbucket.org
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    HostKeyAlias bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyA


Host myteam2.bitbucket.org
    Hostname bitbucket.org
    HostKeyAlias bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyB
```

Then when you clone-from or push-to URLs using fake hostnames like `hg clone ssh://hg@myteam2.bitbucket.org/myteam2/myproject` ssh will swap in the real hostname and the right key.

But really, just use `ssh-agent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can override your key on your repository hgrc level

see [Configuration files for Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#files)

Comment: You can't directly specify the ssh key in a hgrc file.  You can specify user/password for http connections in an `[auth]` section, but the only `key` it takes is a client side certificate for https certificate authentication -- nothing for ssh.